Go recursive algo generate bogus data when the number of elements exceeds 5
Here's a very simple program that enumerates all the possible combinations of a list of elements. The problem is that when the number of elements is equal or bigger than 5, it would generate bogus result.
package main
import "fmt"

func Combination(choices []int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{}
    if len(choices) == 0 {
        result = append(result, choices)
        return result
    } else {
        head := choices[0]
        tail := choices[1:]
        for _, combo := range Combination(tail) {
            result = append(result, combo)
            result = append(result, append(combo, head))
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    for idx, c := range Combination([]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}) {
        fmt.Println(idx, c)
    }
}

And the reuslt is
...
30 [4 3 2 0]
31 [4 3 2 0 0]

I have spent quite some time but still clueless. I doubt it could be the len, cap quirkness of the slice but I an not sure.
Thanks
It should generate all the possible combinations of the elements.

The reason the line result = append(result, append(combo, head)) modifies combo in place, it leads to undesired side effects where combinations are corrupted.
Since slice in go is reference type, append may either modify its argument in-place or return a copy of its argument with an additional entry
    a := []int{1, 2, 3}
    // return a copy of its argument
    a = append(a, 4)
    fmt.Println(a)
    // modify its argument in-place
    _ = append(a[:3], 5)
    fmt.Println(a)

So the right way to do that is:
package main

import "fmt"

func Combination(choices []int) [][]int {
    result := [][]int{}
    if len(choices) == 0 {
        result = append(result, []int{})
        return result
    } else {
        head := choices[0]
        tail := choices[1:]
        for _, combo := range Combination(tail) {
            result = append(result, combo)

            // Create a new combination
            newCombo := make([]int, len(combo))
            // Copy combo elemtnets to newCombo
            copy(newCombo, combo)
            // Adding head to a new slice
            newCombo = append(newCombo, head)

            result = append(result, newCombo)
        }
    }
    return result
}

func main() {
    for idx, c := range Combination([]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}) {
        fmt.Println(idx, c)
    }
}

